# Total Sum of rows that fit criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet where I am trying to add all of a certain ticker's volume,  then paste the ticker name and the total sum to the right of range of data.  Here is how my spreed sheet looks like

```
<ticker<date>  <open>   <high>     <low>    <close>    <vol>       
A   20160101    41.81   42.36365509 41.81   4854841.81  0000001     
A   20160104    41.06   1.305047274 40.34   3287340.69  0000002            
A   20160105    40.73   0.902213812 40.34   2587240.55  0000003
A   20160106    40.24   0.71801573  40.05   2103640.73  0000004
B   20160107    40.14   3.227402925 38.81   3504339.34  3504305
B   20160108    39.22   0.716412187 38.47   3736738.59  3736705
B   20160111    38.71   0.206870243 37.41   2818637.94  2818605
```

This is where I am trying to end up, With the sum of a certain ticker's volume and it's ticker value printed to cells to the right of the data range.

```
<ticker<date>  <open>   <high>     <low>    <close>    <vol>       <ticker> <vol>
A   20160101    41.81   42.36365509 41.81   4854841.81  0000001      A        10
A   20160104    41.06   1.305047274 40.34   3287340.69  0000002      B        15
A   20160105    40.73   0.902213812 40.34   2587240.55  0000003      C         4
A   20160106    40.24   0.71801573  40.05   2103640.73  0000004
B   20160107    40.14   3.227402925 38.81   3504339.34  0000005
B   20160108    39.22   0.716412187 38.47   3736738.59  0000005
B   20160111    38.71   0.206870243 37.41   2818637.94  0000005
C   20160111    38.71   0.206870243 37.41   2818637.94  0000002
C   20160111    38.71   0.206870243 37.41   2818637.94  0000002
```

As of now my macro breaks at the "Does not compare, instead copies & paste" flag.  Where the IF statement does not compare, instead it copies if it does not crash the excel program.

```
Sub totalVolume()
Dim tickSum As Long

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A:A").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("I1"), unique:=True

tickerRecordLength = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
tickerLength = Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row

For tl = 1 To tickerLength
    tickSum = 1
    tickerValue = Cells(tl, 9).Value
    'MsgBox (tickerValue)

    For tlr = 1 To tickerRecordLength    
********************** Does not compare, instead copies & paste **********************
        If Cells(tlr, 1).Value = tickerValue Then
***************************************************************************************
            MsgBox ("tickerRecord: " + Str(tickerRecord))
            MsgBox ("tickerValue: " + Str(tickerValue))
            'Cells(tlr, 6).Value = Cells(tlr, 6).Value + Cells(tlr, 7).Value
        End If
    Next tlr

    Cells(tl, 10).Value = tickSum

Next tl


End Sub
```

Comment: Did you consider to use SUMIF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SUMIF is what you need, either in code or, if you want to have the sum showing on the sheet, you can plant the formula in the cells for all to see - this 2-liner gets round any looping at all, the 2nd line just floods the formula down the rows created by the first line:

```
Sub totalVolume()
    Range("A:A").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("I1"), unique:=True
    Range("J2:J" & Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=SUMIF(A:A,I2,G:G)"
End Sub
```

Although for good practice may I also recommend using Option Explicit and defining your sheets by name etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use application.SumIf and cancel your second loop like this (work for me and with your data sample) :

```
Sub totalVolume()

Range("A:A").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("I1"), unique:=True

tickerLength = Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row

For tl = 2 To tickerLength Step 1

    tickerValue = Cells(tl, 9).Value
    ActiveSheet.Cells(tl, 10) = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), tickerValue, Range("G:G"))

Next tl

End Sub
```